# strOptions aren't applied to str

Tags: r

Here's My data:

```
structure(list(SHOP_WEEK = c(200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L, 200607L), SHOP_DATE = c(20060415L, 20060413L, 20060416L, 20060415L, 20060415L, 20060412L, 20060413L, 20060413L, 20060413L, 20060415L, 20060415L, 20060415L, 20060415L, 20060416L, 20060412L, 20060415L, 20060415L, 20060415L, 20060413L, 20060415L), SHOP_WEEKDAY = c(7L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L), SHOP_HOUR = c(19L, 20L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 19L), QUANTITY = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), SPEND = c(0.93, 1.03, 0.98, 3.07, 4.81, 0.28, 1.56, 0.84, 1.09, 1.62, 1.85, 1.11, 1.49, 1.3, 2.21, 0.81, 1.25, 3.34, 3.34, 0.01), PROD_CODE = c("26", "70", "88", "99", "160", "249", "391", "393", "437", "506", "509", "531", "723", "731", "1145", "1154", "1155", "1418", "1418", "1536"), PROD_CODE_10 = c("188", "1", "61", "188", "50", "68", "74", "162", "158", "192", "161", "135", "72", "158", "10", "15", "108", "71", "71", "201"), PROD_CODE_20 = c("64", "1", "19", "64", "13", "20", "22", "55", "55", "66", "55", "48", "21", "55", "3", "4", "39", "21", "21", "68"), PROD_CODE_30 = c("20", "1", "7", "20", "5", "7", "7", "16", "16", "21", "16", "13", "7", "16", "2", "3", "10", "7", "7", "21"), PROD_CODE_40 = c("5", "1", "2", "5", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "5", "3", "3", "2", "3", "1", "1", "3", "2", "2", "5"), CUST_CODE = c("709", "1108", NA, "709", "709", "1108", NA, "1108", NA, "709", "709", "709", "709", NA, "1108", "709", "709", "709", "1108", "709"), CUST_PRICE_SENSITIVITY = c("3", "1", NA, "3", "3", "1", NA, "1", NA, "3", "3", "3", "3", NA, "1", "3", "3", "3", "1", "3"), CUST_LIFESTAGE = c("3", "6", NA, "3", "3", "6", NA, "6", NA, "3", "3", "3", "3", NA, "6", "3", "3", "3", "6", "3"), BASKET_ID = c("1964", "2690", "680", "1964", "1964", "2689", "687", "2690", "687", "1964", "1964", "1964", "1964", "680", "2689", "1964", "1964", "1964", "2690", "1964"), BASKET_SIZE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", "M", "S"), class = "factor"), BASKET_PRICE_SENSITIVITY = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("LA", "MM", "UM", "XX"), class = "factor"),     BASKET_TYPE = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L,     2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Full Shop",     "Small Shop", "Top Up", "XX"), class = "factor"), BASKET_DOMINANT_MISSION = structure(c(3L,     1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L,     3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Fresh", "Grocery", "Mixed",     "Nonfood", "XX"), class = "factor"), STORE_CODE = c("1",     "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",     "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), STORE_FORMAT = structure(c(1L,     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("LS", "MS", "SS", "XLS"), class = "factor"),     STORE_REGION = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("E01",     "E02", "E03", "N01", "N02", "N03", "S01", "S02", "S03", "W01",     "W02", "W03"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("SHOP_WEEK", "SHOP_DATE", "SHOP_WEEKDAY", "SHOP_HOUR", "QUANTITY", "SPEND", "PROD_CODE", "PROD_CODE_10", "PROD_CODE_20", "PROD_CODE_30", "PROD_CODE_40", "CUST_CODE", "CUST_PRICE_SENSITIVITY", "CUST_LIFESTAGE", "BASKET_ID", "BASKET_SIZE", "BASKET_PRICE_SENSITIVITY", "BASKET_TYPE", "BASKET_DOMINANT_MISSION", "STORE_CODE", "STORE_FORMAT", "STORE_REGION"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's my current str:

```
   > str(f)
'data.frame':   25241 obs. of  22 variables:
 $ SHOP_WEEK               : int  200607 200607 200607 200607 200607 200607 200607 200607 
200607 200607 ...
 $ SHOP_DATE               : int  20060415 20060413 20060416 20060415 20060415 20060412 
20060413 20060413 20060413 20060415 ...
 $ SHOP_WEEKDAY            : int  7 5 1 7 7 4 5 5 5 7 ...
 $ SHOP_HOUR               : int  19 20 14 19 19 19 18 20 18 19 ...
 $ QUANTITY                : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 ...
 $ SPEND                   : num  0.93 1.03 0.98 3.07 4.81 0.28 1.56 0.84 1.09 1.62 ...
 $ PROD_CODE               : chr  "26" "70" "88" "99" ...
 $ PROD_CODE_10            : chr  "188" "1" "61" "188" ...
 $ PROD_CODE_20            : chr  "64" "1" "19" "64" ...
```

And so on...

To no avail, I've tried setting various options like so:

```
strOptions(vec.length=2,strict.width=T) # Works for factors only, not ints
options(width=83) # Still puts the extra chars on another line
str(f,vec.length=2)
```

**How do I set the string options correctly?**

Comment: hey whats the value of `getOption("width")`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the width like this

`options(width=as.integer(value))`

or like this

`options("width"= value)`

Comment: `options("width")` sets the characters til a return, it doesn't limit output even with `strOptions(strict.width=T)` set. WIth that being said, I did try it, but it didn't work. thanks for the help tho. The main point in my post is setting options in the `strOptions` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `options(width=as.integer(value))` didn't work as well?